# How do I include a .js file in html loaded with a json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, backbone.js

I need to display an instance of a javascript class that's loaded with data from .json file with using require.js in backbone.

I have the following js and json files:

collections/Companies.js

```
define([
    'models/Company'
], function(CompanyModel) {
    'use strict';

    var CompanyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: CompanyModel
    });

    return CompanyCollection;
});
```

data/companies.json

```
[{
    "id": 1000001,
    "name": "Test Company 1",
    "description": "this is a test company that should be displayed"
},
{
    "id": 1000002,
    "name": "Test Company 2",
    "description": "this is another test company that should be displayed as well"
}]
```

Also, I have the following code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="data/companies.json" src="collections/Companies.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       require(["collections/Companies"],
        function(Companies){
            $("#json").append(Companies[0].id);
            alert("test");
        }
       );
    </script>

    <div id="json"></div>
```

Of course it is not working as I intended and I can't figure out the correct syntax and/or iteration logic.
How can I load the .js class with the data from the .json file?
My `<script type="text/javascript" data-main...` line doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance and sorry if I'm not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requirejs` is usually used to load scripts and template files but you can use it to load a `.json` file as well. but you have to parse it yourself using `JSON.parse`.

You have 2 different options,

using [requirejs text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text/blob/master/text.js), like:

```
require(["collections/Companies", "text!data/companies.json"],
    function(Companies, CompaniesJSONStr) {
        var CompaniesJSON = JSON.parse(CompaniesJSONStr);

    }
);
```

or using [requirejs plugins](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins), which it again uses `text!` plugin:

```
require.config({
    paths : {
        json: 'data'
    }
});

define([ 'collections/Companies', 'json!companies.json' ],
    function(Companies, CompaniesJSON){

    }
);
```

Comment: And how do I load the json file into the class?